# What's a good package for typesetting quantum circuits?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to typeset things that [look like](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/quantum-circuit/)

[image]

I'm already aware of

- Q-circuit, which has nice custom macros for this purpose, but is based on the relatively slow and clunky XyPic
- TikZ, which I can use to manually set things up (that's how the picture I've hotlinked was drawn)

Are there any other alternatives I should know about?

Comment: Quantum circuits are written in a similar way to sheet music. It'd be interesting if [LilyPond](http://lilypond.org/) could be adapted/abused to suit this purpose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently Nielsen and Chuang used [qasm2circ](http://www.media.mit.edu/quanta/qasm2circ/) to produce the figures in [Quantum Computation and Quantum Information](http://www.squint.org/qci/).

Comment: qasm2circ is also based on xypic, apparently. So it suffers from the same criticisms that the OP gave for qcircuit.

Comment: OP's primary objection to XyPic was speed, which matters if you're using it every time you build your document (which is the standard workflow for Q-circuit).  The workflow for qasm2circ is to build the quantum circuit diagrams beforehand and then use `\includegraphics`, which offsets the slowness of XyPic (and is a better workflow for preparing documents for publication).  And regardless of the OP's objections to XyPic, the fact that qasm2circ was used to produce the quantum circuit diagrams for _the_ book on quantum computation makes it an important alternative to be aware of.

Comment: I try to use qasm2circ in Ubuntu with the command `qasm2pdf` in terminal, but it outputs that `qasm2pdf: command not found`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 19):

The image you link to was a diagram I did in TikZ a few years ago. It's not a particularly efficient way of doing it either. These days I'd typeset that using a TikZ matrix environment. The only real option specific to quantum circuits were qasm2circ and q-circuit. I don't like the output they generate though, and TikZ is really the way to go in my opinion. Sure, it may require a few more key strokes, but I think the effort pays off. One important point to make is that TikZ can be slow, but if you get it to externalise TikZ images then it becomes as fast as a normal `\includegraphics` after a single slow compilation per diagram.

A revised version of the example you link to which may be more inspirational follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

% TikZ libraries `calc` needed now to tweak bracket.
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
% Dirac Kets
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\ensuremath{\left|#1\right\rangle}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    % `operator' will only be used by Hadamard (H) gates here.
    % `phase' is used for controlled phase gates (dots).
    % `surround' is used for the background box.
    \tikzstyle{operator} = [draw,fill=white,minimum size=1.5em] 
    \tikzstyle{phase} = [draw,fill,shape=circle,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{surround} = [fill=blue!10,thick,draw=black,rounded corners=2mm]
    %
    \matrix[row sep=0.4cm, column sep=0.8cm] (circuit) {
    % First row.
    \node (q1) {\ket{0}}; &[-0.5cm] 
    \node[operator] (H11) {H}; &
    \node[phase] (P12) {}; &
    \node[phase] (P13) {}; &
    &[-0.3cm]
    \coordinate (end1); \\
    % Second row.
    \node (q2) {\ket{0}}; &
    \node[operator] (H21) {H}; &
    \node[phase] (P22) {}; &
    &
    \node[operator] (H24) {H}; &
    \coordinate (end2);\\
    % Third row.
    \node (q3) {\ket{0}}; &
    \node[operator] (H31) {H}; &
    &
    \node[phase] (P33) {}; &
    \node[operator] (H34) {H}; &
    \coordinate (end3); \\
    };
    % Draw bracket on right with resultant state.
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace},thick]
        ($(circuit.north east)-(0cm,0.3cm)$)
        to node[midway,right] (bracket) {$\displaystyle\frac{\ket{000}+\ket{111}}{\sqrt{2}}$}
        ($(circuit.south east)+(0cm,0.3cm)$);
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        % Draw background box.
        \node[surround] (background) [fit = (q1) (H31) (bracket)] {};
        % Draw lines.
        \draw[thick] (q1) -- (end1)  (q2) -- (end2) (q3) -- (end3) (P12) -- (P22) (P13) -- (P33);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    %
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I use your code as a part of a possible package for drawing quantum circuits using TikZ? I may release it under the GNU public license if I can do it. If you can participate on this package development, that will also be great. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @XiaodongQi, I'm afraid I'm not using TeX a lot these days, so I wouldn't be able to actively help you. You're very welcome to use my code though!

Answer (score 11):

Since September 2018 there is the `quantikz` TiKZ library:
https://ctan.org/pkg/quantikz

It has, on purpose, very similar syntax to qcircuit.
For your circuit:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
\gategroup[wires=3,steps=11,style={rounded corners,fill=blue!20}, background]{}
&\lstick{$|{0}\rangle$} & \gate{H}&\ctrl{1} & \ctrl{2} &\qw &\qw 
 \rstick[wires=3]{$\frac{|{000}\rangle + |{111}\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$} 
\\
&\lstick{$|{0}\rangle$} & \gate{H}& \control{} & \qw& \gate{H} &\qw
\\
&\lstick{$|{0}\rangle$} & \gate{H}& \qw & \control{} & \gate{H} &\qw
&&&&
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

Update 23 Dec 2022: In overleaf, quantikz is included when selecting the texlive 2022 distribution for compilation, no need to manually upload the tikzlibraryquantikz.code.tex file.

Comment: Personally I have found `quantikz` to be rather convenient/natural for drawing circuits in research papers — although alignment around `=` signs is a bit awkward. `qpic` is also nice, but it feels like there are more hoops to jump through (it is a tool separate from LaTeX, so not easy to use with Overleaf and similar tools)

Comment: true about overleaf, you have to upload the tikzlibrary file and it cannot be put in a subfolder, but otherwise it works file (even externalization)

Comment: There is a Julia library that can be used to programmatically generate the required markup as well: Quantikz.jl https://krastanov.github.io/Quantikz/stable/

Comment: @MarcusPS there is now the "align equals at" option for easy alignment

Answer (score 5):

You might also want to look at the qcircuit package:
https://www.ctan.org/pkg/qcircuit

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [⟨q|pic⟩](https://github.com/qpic/qpic) at the moment for my work, which uses TikZ. It's been flexible enough for me so far, and there's lots of examples on the GitHub page linked but I'll include a couple of the examples here:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is `circuitikz` for drawing circuits with TiKZ.

Comment: The circuitikz package is for drawing electrical circuits; quantum circuits are almost completely different.  It might be adaptable, but then you probably might as well be using plain TikZ.

Comment: That's fair enough.