# How to plot quantum logical gates with tikz？

Tags: circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib, pst-circ, circuits

I have seen many examples of classical circuit with tikz but none of [quantum logical gates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gate). Here are some of the quantum logical gates

[image: SWAP gate]
[image: Hadamard gate]
[image: controlled NOT gate]
[image: controlled-U gate]
[image: Toffoli gate]
[image: Fredkin gate]

A whole circuit maybe look like
[image: quantum logical circuit]

Comment: A circuitikz multinode element should have anchor names for each of the connection points.   You place the elements on a grid and draw lines between the anchors.  Bipole elements are generally placed between circuit nodes using "to".

Comment: BTW, is there a standard nomenclature for the contact points?   In and out are standard for bipoles and pin numbers for ICs.

Comment: @JohnKormylo [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gate) lists the name of each gate above. Maybe there is no nomenclature for the contact points, but we can give one similar to the ones in Circuitikz.

Comment: From the article, especially the table for the Fredkin gate, in (or in1, in2, ...) out and control seem to be standard.  Not sure what the 6 lead U gate is about.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Do you mean the controlled-U gate?

Comment: I meant the U gate used in the whole circuit diagram (above and in the answer).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Maybe it's proper to numerate from up to down, left side: (in1, in2, in3) and right side: (out1, out2, out3).

Comment: If so, could we replace it with 3 separate u-gates?  Do we really need a multilead u-gate or h-gate component?

Comment: @JohnKormylo No, u-gate acts on the three qubits and can not be separable generally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inspired by the code given by `@qubyte` [HERE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44270/34618) and after adding some new quantum logic gates and patience, drawing the plot is possible.

Information: [more inform](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9767/34618)

[image]

Code

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
% `operator' will only be used by Hadamard (H) gates here.
% `operator2' is for large U gates
% `phase' is used for controlled phase gates (dots).
% `surround' is used for the background box.
% `crossx' is used for the cross.
% `circlewc' is used for the circle with cross box.
\tikzset{
operator/.style = {draw,fill=white,minimum size=1.5em},
operator2/.style = {draw,fill=white,minimum height=3cm},
phase/.style = {draw,fill,shape=circle,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt},
surround/.style = {fill=blue!10,thick,draw=black,rounded corners=2mm},
cross/.style={path picture={ 
\draw[thick,black](path picture bounding box.north) -- (path picture bounding box.south) (path picture bounding box.west) -- (path picture bounding box.east);
}},
crossx/.style={path picture={ 
\draw[thick,black,inner sep=0pt]
(path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west) (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.north east);
}},
circlewc/.style={draw,circle,cross,minimum width=0.3 cm},
}
    %
\matrix[row sep=0.4cm, column sep=0.8cm] (circuit) { % 9 columns
    % First row.
\node (q1) {\ket{\psi}};  
& [-0.5cm] 
& 
&%\node[operator](U11){U};                                     
& 
&  
&  
&[-0.3cm]
&
\coordinate (end1); \\
    % Second row.
\node (q2) {\ket{0}};    
&                                     
&\node[operator] (H21) {H}; 
&\node[](U21){};                                      
&\node[phase] (P21) {};
&\node[operator] (H22) {H};
&\node[phase] (P22) {};   
& \node[crossx] (c21){};
&\coordinate (end2);\\
    % Third row.
\node (q3) {\ket{0}};    
&                                      
&\node[operator] (H31) {H}; 
&%\node[](U31){};                                      
&\node[circlewc] (P31) {};   
& 
&\node[circlewc] (P32) {};                                               
& \node[crossx] (c31){};
&\coordinate (end3);\\
};

% Draw bracket on right with resultant state.
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace},thick]
        ($(end1)+(2pt,0)$)
        to node[midway,right] (bracket) {$\ket{\phi^+}$}
        ($(end2)+(2pt,0)$);
\node at ($(end3)+(10pt,0)$){$\ket{\psi}$};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw[thick] (q1) -- (end1)  
(q2) -- (end2) 
(q3) -- (end3) 
(P21) -- (P31)  (P22) -- (P32);
\draw[thick,shorten >=-4pt,shorten <=-4pt](c21)--(c31);
\foreach \i in {-3,-0.4,4}{
\draw[dashed,thick,red] ([xshift=\i cm]circuit.north) -- ([xshift=\i cm]circuit.south); 
\node[operator2] at (U21){U};  %<-- for large U
}
\end{pgfonlayer}
    %
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Missing code `\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\ensuremath{\left|#1\right\rangle}}`

Comment: Can I use your code as a part of a possible package for drawing quantum circuits using TikZ? I may release it under the GNU public license if I can do it. If you can participate on this package development, that will also be great. I will also contact the linked original author... Thanks.

Comment: @XiaodongQi: Yes, please feel free to use it, if it gives you some idea to move on, leading to completion of your package.  It  would be my honer, really.

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is an old question, and I used some of the excellent answers already present in what I've done, but I have recently produced a tikz library called quantikz that helps to typeset quantum circuits. There's a full tutorial available [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.03842). (It's also a route to downloading the package, by looking at the source code, but hopefully in a day or two, it'll be available through ctan.)

I reproduced the target circuit:
[image]
with the following code (and loading the quantikz library in the document preamble):

```
\begin{tikzcd}
\lstick{\ket{\psi}}\slice{} & \qw & \gate[wires=3]{U}\slice{} & \qw & \qw & \qw\slice{} & \rstick[wires=2]{\ket{\phi^+}}\qw \\
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{H} & & \ctrl{1} & \gate{H} & \ctrl{1} & \qw \\
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{H} & \phantom{wide} & \targ{} & \qw & \targ{} & \rstick{\ket{\psi}}\qw
\end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: Have you put the code somewhere else? It would be great to contribute to the code in order to make small improvements. Btw, this is the greatest tool I've been using lately for quantum circuit design and the switch from `qcircuit` is really easy. At the  moment, after a few days of usage, the only thing I really miss is the `nghost` and `cghost` macros, but the pros of this package really outweigh the cons.

Comment: I haven't put it anywhere like github so that people can directly suggest changes. Please feel free to email me. There are already several user-requested features that I've added and am yet to upload, along with some improvement in spacing. nghost and cghost hadn't previously impinged upon my conciousness. I'll have a look at adding an equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The swap gate is implemented using two bipoles.  The disadvantage is that you have to add a line between the two centers.  The advantage is that you don't have to worry about how far apart they are.

[image: circuit elements]

I moved the default label location to the bottom so as to avoid the control anchor.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\newlength{\ResRight}
\newlength{\ResUp}

\makeatletter
\def\TikzBipolePath#1#2{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{#1}{#2}}
\def\CircDirection{\pgf@circ@direction}
\makeatother

% h-gate

\ctikzset{bipoles/hgate/width/.initial=.65}
\ctikzset{bipoles/hgate/height/.initial=.65}
\ctikzset{bipoles/hgate/symbol/.initial=\textit{\Large H}}

\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/hgate/height}}
  {hgate}
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/hgate/height}}
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/hgate/width}}
  {
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}
    \pgfusepath{draw}
    \pgftext[rotate=-\CircDirection]{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/hgate/symbol}}
  }

\def\hgatepath#1{\TikzBipolePath{hgate}{#1}}
\tikzset{hgate/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\hgatepath, l_=#1}}

% u-gate

\ctikzset{bipoles/ugate/width/.initial=.65}
\ctikzset{bipoles/ugate/height/.initial=.65}
\ctikzset{bipoles/ugate/symbol/.initial=\textit{\Large U}}

\pgfcircdeclarebipole
  {
  \anchor{control}{
    \pgfextracty{\ResUp}{\northeast}
    \pgfpoint{0}{\ResUp}
  }}
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/ugate/height}}
  {ugate}
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/ugate/height}}
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/ugate/width}}
  {
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}
    \pgfusepath{draw}
    \pgftext[rotate=-\CircDirection]{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/ugate/symbol}}
  }

\def\ugatepath#1{\TikzBipolePath{ugate}{#1}}
\tikzset{ugate/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\ugatepath, l_=#1}}

% cnot gate

\ctikzset{bipoles/cnot/width/.initial=.4}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cnot/height/.initial=.4}

\pgfcircdeclarebipole
  {
    \anchor{control}{
    \pgfextracty{\ResUp}{\northeast}
    \pgfpoint{0cm}{\ResUp}
  }}
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cnot/height}}
  {cnot}
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cnot/height}}
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cnot/width}}
  {
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfextractx{\ResRight}{\northeast}
    \pgfextracty{\ResUp}{\northeast}
    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\ResRight}{0cm}}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{\ResUp}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0cm}{\ResUp}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0cm}{-\ResUp}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\ResRight}{0cm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\ResRight}{0cm}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}
  }

\def\cnotpath#1{\TikzBipolePath{cnot}{#1}}
\tikzset{cnot/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\cnotpath, l_=#1}}

% swap gate (half)

\ctikzset{bipoles/swap/width/.initial=.4}
\ctikzset{bipoles/swap/height/.initial=.4}

\pgfcircdeclarebipole
  {\anchor{control}{\pgfpointorigin}}% equivalent to center
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/swap/height}}
  {swap}
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/swap/height}}
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/swap/width}}
  {
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfextractx{\ResRight}{\northeast}
    \pgfextracty{\ResUp}{\northeast}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{.5\ResRight}{.5\ResUp}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-.5\ResRight}{-.5\ResUp}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{.5\ResRight}{-.5\ResUp}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-.5\ResRight}{.5\ResUp}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\ResRight}{0cm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\ResRight}{0cm}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}
  }

\def\swappath#1{\TikzBipolePath{swap}{#1}}
\tikzset{swap/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\swappath, l_=#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}

\draw (0,0) to[hgate=H1] (2,0) to[ugate=U1, n=U1] (4,0) to[cnot=CNOT, n=N1] (5,0) to[swap=SWAP, n=Bottom] (7,0);
\draw (0,1) -- (5,1) to[swap, n=Top] (7,1);
\draw (U1.control) to[short, -*] (3,1);
\draw (N1.control) to[short, -*] (4.5,1);
\draw (Bottom.center) -- (Top.center);

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One could implement the remaining gates using multiple bipole gates with extra anchors.

Comment: Thanks! It will be perfect if you implement the remaining gates in the same tex file. I do not know how to implement them.