# Qcircuit,quantum circuit,game

Tags: circuits

How can I create these two pictures in LaTeX, which are difficult to make out but on the l.h.s. on your screen, right under the title "Figures and tables" [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167923608001292). Can someone give me code for Qcircuit LaTeX?

The pictures are:

[image]

and

[image]

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\input{Qcircuit} 
\begin{document} 
\Qcircuit @C=1em @R=1em { \lstick{\ket{x}} & \qw \ar@{.}[]+<3.5em,1em>; [d]+<3.5em,-1em> 
& \ctrl{1} &
 \qw & \rstick{\ket{x}} \qw \\ 
\lstick{\ket{y}} & \gate{H} & 
\gate{\pi} & \gate{H} & \rstick{\ket{y \oplus x}} \qw } 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't make them out, but circuitikz supports some quantum components.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199683/how-to-plot-quantum-logical-gates-with-tikz

Comment: And can you make them out in "circuitikz" at least?I really need them :-(

Comment: I mean I can't tell what they are supposed to look like - too small and dim.

Comment: Look here is a pdf    http://ulozto.cz/xKsktGpk/a-survey-of-quantum-games-pdf  page 321

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: I've added your code to the question and tidied up the question a bit. Please tidy up the MWE by using some line breaks to make it readable, and make the third URL a link people can click on. Your aim should make it as easy as possible for people to help you - if your question is frustrating, people are less likely to go to the trouble of understanding and answering it.

Answer (score 4):

Jan contacted me directly, and I answered this question for him, but I'll post the answer here in case someone needs something similar.

The LaTeX source and resulting PDFs for these two circuits are included below:

Nesting horizontally stacked gates:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{rotating}

\input{Qcircuit}

\newcommand{\puremultigate}[2]{*+<1em,.9em>{\hphantom{#2}} \POS [0,0]="i",[0,0].[#1,0]="e",!C *{#2},"e"+UR;"e"+UL **\dir{-};"e"+DL **\dir{-};"e"+DR **\dir{-};"e"+UR **\dir{-},"i"}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
\vspace{-.6em}\\
\Qcircuit @R=.2em @C=.5em @!R {
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \puremultigate{5}{\rotatebox{-90}{\small Measurement}} \\
& & \qw & \qw & \multigate{3}{U} & \qw & \qw & \multigate{3}{\fbox{$U_1$\rule[-1em]{0em}{2.7em}}\ \,\fbox{$U_2$\rule[-1em]{0em}{2.7em}}} & \qw & \qw & \multigate{3}{U^\dagger} & \qw & \qw & \ghost{\rotatebox{-90}{\small Measurement}} & \qw & \qw \\
& \lstick{\raisebox{-1.5em}{$\rho$}} & \qw & \qw & \ghost{U} & \qw & \qw & \ghost{\fbox{$U_1$\rule[-1em]{0em}{2.7em}}\ \,\fbox{$U_2$\rule[-1em]{0em}{2.7em}}} & \qw & \qw & \ghost{U^\dagger} & \qw & \qw & \ghost{\rotatebox{-90}{\small Measurement}} & \qw & \qw \\
& & & \raisebox{.3em}{\vdots} & \pureghost{U} & \push{\rule{3em}{0em}} & & \pureghost{\fbox{$U_1$\rule[-1em]{0em}{2.7em}}\ \,\fbox{$U_2$\rule[-1em]{0em}{2.7em}}} & \push{\rule{.5em}{0em}} & & \pureghost{U^\dagger} & \push{\rule{1.5em}{0em}} & & \pureghost{\rotatebox{-90}{\small Measurement}} & & \\
& & \qw & \qw & \ghost{U} & \qw & \qw & \ghost{\fbox{$U_1$\rule[-1em]{0em}{2.7em}}\ \,\fbox{$U_2$\rule[-1em]{0em}{2.7em}}} & \qw & \qw & \ghost{U^\dagger} & \qw & \qw & \ghost{\rotatebox{-90}{\small Measurement}} & \qw & \qw \\
\push{\rule{.6em}{0em}} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &
}
\vspace{1.2em}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Horizontally nested quantum gates]

Nesting vertically stacked gates:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{rotating}

\input{Qcircuit}

\newcommand{\puremultigate}[2]{*+<1em,.9em>{\hphantom{#2}} \POS [0,0]="i",[0,0].[#1,0]="e",!C *{#2},"e"+UR;"e"+UL **\dir{-};"e"+DL **\dir{-};"e"+DR **\dir{-};"e"+UR **\dir{-},"i"}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
\vspace{-.6em}\\
\Qcircuit @R=.2em @C=.5em @!R {
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \puremultigate{5}{\rotatebox{-90}{\small Measurement}} \\
& & \qw & \qw & \multigate{3}{U} & \qw & \qw & \multigate{3}{\parbox{2em}{\fbox{$U_1$}\vspace{.2em}\\\fbox{$U_2$}}} & \qw & \qw & \multigate{3}{U^\dagger} & \qw & \qw & \ghost{\rotatebox{-90}{\small Measurement}} & \qw & \qw \\
& \lstick{\raisebox{-1.5em}{$\rho$}} & \qw & \qw & \ghost{U} & \qw & \qw & \ghost{\parbox{2em}{\fbox{$U_1$}\vspace{.2em}\\\fbox{$U_2$}}} & \qw & \qw & \ghost{U^\dagger} & \qw & \qw & \ghost{\rotatebox{-90}{\small Measurement}} & \qw & \qw \\
& & & \raisebox{.3em}{\vdots} & \pureghost{U} & \push{\rule{3em}{0em}} & & \pureghost{\parbox{2em}{\fbox{$U_1$}\vspace{.2em}\\\fbox{$U_2$}}} & \push{\rule{.5em}{0em}} & & \pureghost{U^\dagger} & \push{\rule{1.5em}{0em}} & & \pureghost{\rotatebox{-90}{\small Measurement}} & & \\
& & \qw & \qw & \ghost{U} & \qw & \qw & \ghost{\parbox{2em}{\fbox{$U_1$}\vspace{.2em}\\\fbox{$U_2$}}} & \qw & \qw & \ghost{U^\dagger} & \qw & \qw & \ghost{\rotatebox{-90}{\small Measurement}} & \qw & \qw \\
\push{\rule{.6em}{0em}} & & & & & & & & & & & & & &
}
\vspace{1.2em}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: vertically nested quantum gates]

Qcircuit doesn't have any special functionality for nested gates, but to get a nested gate effect, one can simply insert boxes representing the inner gates into a standard \multigate command.

In order to get the measurement gate to look right I had to define a new \multigate command, \puremultigate, that doesn’t force a leading wire.  To do this I took the standard definition of \multigate out of Qcircuit.tex and deleted the final \qw command from it.