# How can i draw this circuit diagram?

Tags: graphics

I am trying to draw the following diagram using qcircuit package but failed to do so. Guide me how draw this diagram.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! When you are saying that you are trying: what did you try specifically and where did you get stuck? Please provide us with your attempt in form of a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), i.e. a minimal document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Circuitikz (now) has some built in quantum components.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199683/how-to-plot-quantum-logical-gates-with-tikz

Answer (score 4):

I think the package has not yet implemented how to color the gates, at least nothing is mentioned in the [manual](http://ftp.inf.utfsm.cl/pub/tex-archive/graphics/qcircuit/qcircuit.pdf);Just to learn and fun,an option in qcircuit code embedded in a tikz node , to add the color padding to the gate. Of course you can draw independently using tikz commands, with more colorful results.

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[braket,qm]{qcircuit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[black!20](0,0)++(-21pt,-24pt) rectangle ++(25.8pt,45.5pt);
    \node at (0,0) {
        \Qcircuit @C=2em @R=2.5em {
            \lstick{\ket{0}} &\qw & \multigate{1}{\enspace \textrm P \enspace} & \gate{U_2} & \qw\\
            \hspace{-10pt}\ket{0}^{\otimes n}&{/\!/}\qw &\ghost{\enspace  \textrm P \enspace} & \ctrl{-1} & \qw \\
        }
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```