# How to draw a circuit using quantikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, quantikz

How can one draw this complicated-looking circuit with quantikz?

[image]

Edit: Here is my attempt:

```
 \documentclass[english]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\usepackage{braket}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{quantikz}[thin lines] 
        \lstick{$\ket{\psi_0}$}&    \gate{U}    &              \ctrl{1}               &   \qw     & \ctrl{1}                              &  \gate{V_1} & \gate{V_2} & \qw \\
        \lstick{$\ket{0}$}          &        \qw        & \gate{R_y(\theta_1)}  &    \qw    & \gate{R_y(\theta_2)}   &             &             & \qw       
    \end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried something looking the manual?

Comment: Yep...still trying: \begin{quantikz}[thin lines] 
\lstick{$\ket{\psi_0}$}&    \gate{U} &              \ctrl{1}               &   \qw     & \ctrl{1}                              & \qw    & \gate{V_1} & \gate{V_2} & \qw \\
\lstick{$\ket{0}$}         &        \qw        & \gate{R_y(\theta_1)}  &    \qw    & \gate{R_y(\theta_2)}   &  \qw  &            &             & \qw       
\end{quantikz}

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Zubin Please, read the comment of DG': edit your question.....Thus we can help you better.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastiano. I have just updated my questioin.

Comment: Need to use `\documentclass[english]{revtex4-2}`

Comment: Please see my updated my answer.

Comment: For a historical perspective, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199683/how-to-plot-quantum-logical-gates-with-tikz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't make ot work with your chosen document class, but in standalone it's working. Here are two versions, one without the dotted outline and one with it.

[image: V1]

[image: V2]

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}

    \begin{quantikz}[thin lines] 
            \lstick{$\ket{\psi_0}$}&  \gate{U} & \octrl{1} & \qw & \ctrl{1} &  \gate{V_1} & \gate{V_2} & \qw \\
            \lstick{$\ket{0}$} & \qw & \gate{R_y(\theta_1)} & \qw & \gate{R_y(\theta_2)} & \octrl{-1} & \ctrl{-1} & \qw       
    \end{quantikz}
    
    \begin{quantikz}[thin lines] 
            \lstick{$\ket{\psi_0}$}& \qw &  \gate{U} \gategroup[wires=2,steps=6,style={dotted,cap=round,inner sep=10pt}]{} & \octrl{1} & \qw & \ctrl{1} &  \gate{V_1} & \gate{V_2} & \qw & \qw \\
            \lstick{$\ket{0}$} & \qw &\qw & \gate{R_y(\theta_1)} & \qw & \gate{R_y(\theta_2)} & \octrl{-1} & \ctrl{-1} & \qw  & \qw     
    \end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

#### EDIT: works on revtex4-2 document class

```
\documentclass[english]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}

    \begin{quantikz}[thin lines] 
            \lstick{$\ket{\psi_0}$}&  \gate{U} & \octrl{1} & \qw & \ctrl{1} &  \gate{V_1} & \gate{V_2} & \qw \\
            \lstick{$\ket{0}$} & \qw & \gate{R_y(\theta_1)} & \qw & \gate{R_y(\theta_2)} & \octrl{-1} & \ctrl{-1} & \qw       
    \end{quantikz}
    
    \begin{quantikz}[thin lines,node distance=2pt] 
            \lstick{$\ket{\psi_0}$}& \qw &  \gate{U} \gategroup[wires=2,steps=6,style={dotted,cap=round,inner sep=10pt}]{} & \octrl{1} & \qw & \ctrl{1} &  \gate{V_1} & \gate{V_2} & \qw & \qw \\
            \lstick{$\ket{0}$} & \qw &\qw & \gate{R_y(\theta_1)} & \qw & \gate{R_y(\theta_2)} & \octrl{-1} & \ctrl{-1} & \qw  & \qw     
    \end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: on revtex4-2]

Comment: Thanks, @SebGlav. Is it possible to reduce the size such that this fits in one column in a two-column format?

Comment: Or any other better way of drawing the same circuit?

Comment: I don't know about resizing with `quantikz`. I tried several obvious solutions that failed. You can try and design with older packages, like `circuitikz`, or `qcircuit`, but I don' master them to say if a resizing is possible. You could ask this as a new question, and I'm sure you'll get answers.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is very close to the solution.

(1) Need to use `revtex4-2`.

(2) For two columns, you can use `\resizebox`.

(I used the code from SebGlav answer)

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[aps,reprint]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\usepackage{braket}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % added 

\begin{document}    
    
1.  \kant[11]

\noindent   \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{% code from SebGlav answer
    \begin{quantikz}[thin lines] 
        \lstick{$\ket{\psi_0}$}& \qw &  \gate{U} \gategroup[wires=2,steps=6,style={dotted,cap=round,inner sep=10pt}]{} & \octrl{1} & \qw & \ctrl{1} &  \gate{V_1} & \gate{V_2} & \qw & \qw \\
        \lstick{$\ket{0}$} & \qw &\qw & \gate{R_y(\theta_1)} & \qw & \gate{R_y(\theta_2)} & \octrl{-1} & \ctrl{-1} & \qw  & \qw     
    \end{quantikz}
}

\medskip
2.  \kant[2]
    
\tikzset{operator/.append style={fill=red!20}}  
        
\noindent   \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{% code from SebGlav answer
 \begin{quantikz}[thin lines] 
\lstick{$\ket{\psi_0}$}& \qw &  \gate{U} \gategroup[2,steps=6,style={dashed,rounded corners,fill=blue!20,inner sep=10pt},background]{} & \octrl{1} & \qw & \ctrl{1} &  \gate{V_1} & \gate{V_2} & \qw & \qw \\
\lstick{$\ket{0}$} & \qw &\qw & \gate{R_y(\theta_1)} & \qw & \gate{R_y(\theta_2)} & \octrl{-1} & \ctrl{-1} & \qw  & \qw     
\end{quantikz}
}   

\medskip
3.  \kant[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Simon. Is there a better way of drawing the same circuit, by compacting its size (to fit in a single column of a two column format) and maybe beautify it a little bit?

Comment: @Zubin I updated my answer. Beauty is in the eye of the beholder