# Quantikz: how to draw zig-zag lines connecting gates on different wires?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, quantikz

I want to draw a zig-zag line between two gates on different wires (to represent entanglement) using [quantikz](https://ctan.org/pkg/quantikz). So far I've only managed to join the gates using a straight wire by making use of a control operation, however what I want is to represent entanglement, not control. Is it possible to do this? The manual is very vague and doesn't describe any method such as this.

Below is a minimum working example where two gates are connected with a straight wire (control), as discussed

```
\begin{quantikz}[column sep=0.2cm]
\qw & \gate{}\ctrl{1} & \qw \\
\qw & \gate{}\targ{} & \qw
\end{quantikz}
```

which looks like this:

[image]

How can I replace the straight line with a zig-zag?

Comment: Alas, quantikz doesn't parse antyhing like TikZ.  You might look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199683/how-to-plot-quantum-logical-gates-with-tikz

Answer (score 1):

Quantikz is built on the tikz-cd package and so you can use tikz-cd code within the quantikz environment. For producing a zigzag, the arrow command can be used with appropriately selected options.

To achieve what you want, the following code can be used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[graphics,tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\newlength{\imagewidth}
\newlength{\imagescale}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\begin{document}

    \begin{quantikz}[column sep=0.2cm]
    \qw & \gate{} \arrow[d, squiggly, no head, no tail] & \qw \\
    \qw & \gate{} & \qw \\
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

This produces the output:

[image]

Additional customisation of the line drawn is available with tikz-cd, as detailed in the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd?lang=en).